# Battery showing 15 to 16 volt

Tags: battery

Turning on ignition just get click as though loose battery connection, battery showing  (high ) 15 to 16 volts but still won't turn over had to get push. Anyone got any ideas on this one.

Comment: What type of vehicle is it?

Answer (score 1):

You would get the clicking symptom due to -

- Starter motor brushes being worn out.
- Starter solenoid contacts being burnt out.
- The thick wire from the battery to the starter solenoid being disconnected.

Are you sure your battery voltage reading is correct?

Presumably once started, the engine continues to run correctly and the lights work?

Comment: Also, check the battery voltage while trying to start.

Comment: Perhaps also check the battery in the voltmeter if it is a digital device. Analog versions don't use a battery for voltage readings, but you can't trust a digital meter with a low battery.